# Why cpu frequency changing and it is not possible to stop this?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, cpu, cpufreq

I am trying to disable cpu frequency scaling and limit the processor to a single speed. But something seem to be changing processor speed constantly. Any ideas on why this is happening?

I am on 16.04 and the processor is A10-7870K and I have disabled frequency scaling from bios. I have both windows and ubuntu installed on the machine. The CPU is not overheating, temperature under 50C at any point.

In windows, the CPU frequency stays at fixed 3.2GHZ. But when I boot into Linux and check `/proc/cpuinfo` I get values all around the place.

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep MHz
cpu MHz         : 2483.111
cpu MHz         : 2511.828
cpu MHz         : 2142.128
cpu MHz         : 1850.386
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Cpufreq module not loaded

```
root@ubuntu:~# lsmod |grep cpufreq
root@ubuntu:~#
```

No settings seem to exist related to cpu frequency scaling

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls -al /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 16 18:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 0 Sep 16 18:37 ..
root@ubuntu:~# find /sys/devices/system/cpu |grep freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq
root@ubuntu:~# find /sys/devices/system/cpu |grep min
root@ubuntu:~# find /sys/devices/system/cpu |grep max
/sys/devices/system/cpu/kernel_max
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

Modern processors (my expertise is Intel, not AMD) will scale back CPU frequency on their own, when the load is light enough, even in performance mode and as a function of what depth of idle state the CPU is going into. I would suggest that you use the acpi-cpufreq CPU frequency scaling driver, and set performance mode. Then you should have a maximum responsiveness for that processor.

There may be other methods, but the only way I know of to absolutely lock all processor CPUs at maximum frequency is to disable any idle state deeper than 0, noting that idle state 0 is not really idle at all, but rather a full load polling state.

Example (while not really relevant, my CPU frequency scaling driver is intel_ptsate, and the governor is "performance"):

```
doug@s15:~/test_kernels$ sudo turbostat --quiet --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgTmp,PkgWatt --interval 5
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt
0.03    1749    283     47      4.04   <<< notice the low CPU frequency, even in performance mode. All Idle states are enabled.
0.02    1737    230     46      4.00
0.03    1920    552     45      4.07
0.02    1779    225     43      3.96
14.08   3498    5958    59      10.53
100.00  3500    40200   63      51.19   <<< Notice the high CPU frequency, but also high power consumption, and increasing package temperature.
100.00  3500    40189   64      51.67   <<< All idle states above 0 are disabled.
100.00  3500    40193   64      51.92   <<< turbostat sees idle state 0 as a "busy" state.
100.00  3500    40200   64      52.04
100.00  3500    40194   65      52.11
100.00  3500    40199   65      52.15
100.00  3500    40199   65      52.24
16.85   3497    7207    46      12.20
0.02    1777    230     45      3.98   <<< All idle states have been enabled again
0.02    1842    227     43      3.96
0.02    1833    224     42      3.94
0.02    1772    233     41      3.92
0.02    1769    249     40      3.91
0.03    1760    280     39      3.90
^C0.02  1922    77      39      3.88
```

Note: My processor is an older i7, and the minimum pstate is 16 (1.6 GHz) and the maximum pstate, with all cores active, is 35 (3.5 GHz)

Comment: Well, it works perfectly fine under Win10 iin same machine. I did not set performance profile under windows even. I simply disabled all related bios options and windows stopped changing frequencies. I don't think my ancient AMD processor is capable of setting its own P-states. If yes, then AMD was years ahead of Intel :p because I read in few places that this feature arrived to Intel processors with Skylake architecture. -> https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Processor_P-states_and_C-states

Comment: @yurtesen. pstates have been around in Intel processors, since well before Skylake. HWP (HardWare Pstates) is a different story, and did start with Skylake (I think). I don't know about windows, but would investigate if what is reported is what is being asked for (like the acpi_cpufreq driver used to do, until a couple of years ago+/-) or what is actually delivered as all scaling drivers in linux now do, for consistency.

Comment: My point was that Linux must be changing the processor speeds, not the processor itself (which seems to be the case for you). Also the problem is that since I disabled it from BIOS, there are NO p-states available to OS. Therefore no driver such as cpufreq etc. are working, as you can see `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq` is empty. Even if there was, this processor can change the multiplier only and the states were set in steps of 100MHz, but as you can see /proc/cpuinfo shows random numbers.

Comment: Yes, agreed, you have no scaling driver running at all and therefore linux is never changing the requested pstate. Yes, speed steps are typically in 100 MHz steps, but the apparent randomness comes from the various ramping up and down and stopping and starting the clock as a function of idle states. Try it for yourself, as turbostat should work for you.